# Add some space between action bar and title in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-actionbar

How can I add some space between action bar and title `textField` ?

**AddWorkRequest**

```
class AddWorkRequest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white
      ),
      child: AddWorkRequestForm(),
    );
  }
}
```

**AddWorkRequestForm**

```
class AddWorkRequestForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return new _AddWorkRequestPage();
  }
}

class _AddWorkRequestPage extends State<AddWorkRequestForm> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Add Work Request"),
        ),
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            titleField(),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 5.0)),
            detailDescriptionField(),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 5.0)),
            locationField(),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 5.0)),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Container(
                child: Text(
                  'Photos',
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontFamily: 'Roboto'),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget detailDescriptionField() {
    return StreamBuilder(builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: StringConstant.detailDescription,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                borderSide: BorderSide()),
          ));
    });
  }

  Widget locationField() {
    return StreamBuilder(builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: StringConstant.location,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                borderSide: BorderSide()),
          ));
    });
  }

  Widget titleField() {
    return StreamBuilder(builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: StringConstant.title,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                borderSide: BorderSide()),
          ));
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap `titleField()` widget in `Padding` and provide only top padding to have more space between action bar and the field, as below:

```
Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: titleField()
            ),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 5.0)),
```

Output is:

[image]

Hope this answers your question.